# Password validation in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

Password validation in dialogflow

Hi

I want to make this job, but i cant uderstand how.

What i need

1. After welcome massage DF asks user a password.
2. User enters phrase
3. If it is = password then DF shows message1 and can get any phrases.
4. If it is not password then DF shows message2 and DF asks user a password again

Now I have a problem on step 4- when user enter phrase from other intents DF shows other response, not message2.

Please help.

**I am tryed webhook**

```
function StartWelcome (agent) {
    // get the employee ID parameter from the request header received from Dialogflow
    let password = agent.parameters.password;
    if (password == 1) { agent.add(agent.request_.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText); }   else { agent.add(`Неправильный пароль! Введите пароль вновь.`); 
    agent.parameters.password = '';
   let intentMap = new Map();
   intentMap.set('StartWelcome', StartWelcome);
   agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

**I tryed context.**

But if user says phrase that is not password but matching to another phrase- DF type responce of matching phrase.

Comment: could you please add more details to the question, eg what you have tried so far?